# Display message after sending email by smtp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a feedback form and send it via email to admin by `SMTP Server`. I have sent it successfully. Now I want to display a **Email sent succeed**
 Message, after sending the email. I am using `Response.Write` but it is not working well. I have used `Ajax` , `Jquery` and many other solutions for this purpose but they are not showing me good results.

**FeedbackController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Comments")] Feedback feedback, string Message)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bool result = false;
        db.Feedbacks.Add(feedback);
        db.SaveChanges();
        result = SendEmail("abc@gmail.com", "Feedback", "<p>Hi Admin,<br/>My name is "+ feedback.Name + ". <br/> E_mail ID: " + feedback.Email + "<br/><br/>" + feedback.Comments + "<br/>Kind Regards,<br/>" + feedback.Name + "</p>");
        Response.Write("Email sent succeed");
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("Create");
    }
    return View(feedback);        
}
```

Comment: You can use `ViewBag` or `JsonResult` to display either standard message or alert box, depending what you need there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Comments")] Feedback feedback, string Message)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //your code    
      TempData["EmailSent"] = "Email sent succeed";   
      return View("Create");
  }
  return View(feedback);
}
```

In your Create View

```
@if (TempData["EmailSent"] != null)
{
    <p>@TempData["EmailSent"].ToString()</p>
}
```

This is just one way of doing it you can make use of `ViewBag` property to achieve this too